# behaviour of ecdf vs geom_function plot to box boundary

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can we control how far to the left and right end of the x-axis the functions in geom_function are plottet?
My minimal example is an ecdf with overlay of geom_function. I use in `geom="point"` for clarity. Why does the red curve (geom_function) stop short of the edges/data?

`ggplot()+stat_ecdf(aes(x=rnorm(100)),geom="point")+geom_function(fun=pnorm,color="red")`

Using `xlim` outside does not seem to change behavior. By reducing the domain with `xlim` the red curve still stops short of the edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)` to remove the expanded x axis:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

xvals <- rnorm(100)

ggplot() + 
  stat_ecdf(aes(x = xvals), geom = "point") + 
  geom_function(fun = pnorm, color = "red", xlim = range(xvals)) +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: that's great, thank you! Is there any way to do the opposite, i.e. to include geom_function in the expansion? Not sure that would make sense.

Comment: @ftonti You set the range of the `geom_function` using the `xlim` argument. You can get the function to stop and start at whatever value you want doing this. Similarly, in `coord_cartesian`, you can get the shown portion of the x axis to be whatever you like.